# Why my SwipeRefreshLayout is null sometimes?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, null

I have a simple app that consists of one MainActivity and 3 fragments. In each of these fragments, I have one SwipeRefreshLayout. In most of the cases when my app loads everything works fine. However, I have noticed when android decides to kill my app and then I open it it causes null pointer exceptions. OnStart I am making a HTTP request to a server and in the on Response method "toggleSwipeRefreshLayoutsOff" is causing the NPE. Unfortunately, I don't have a log since it does not happens every time:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleSwipeRefreshLayoutsOff();
                    }
                });
```

This is my toggleSwipeRefreshLayputsOff method code:

```
 public void toggleSwipeRefreshLayoutsOff() {
    mHourly_forecast_fragment.mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    mCurrent_forecast_fragment.mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    mDaily_forecast_fragment.mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

This is my mainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[] = {"Current", "Hourly", "Daily"};
int Numboftabs = 3;
Current_forecast_fragment mCurrent_forecast_fragment;
Hourly_forecast_fragment mHourly_forecast_fragment;
Daily_forecast_fragment mDaily_forecast_fragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //-----------MY CODE STARTS HERE-----------------
    request = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(1000)
            .setFastestInterval(10 * 1000)
            .setInterval(30 * 60 * 1000);
    locationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(this);

    mainActivityLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_activity_layout);
    changeWindowTopColor();
    this.mCurrent_forecast_fragment = new Current_forecast_fragment();
    this.mHourly_forecast_fragment = new Hourly_forecast_fragment();
    this.mDaily_forecast_fragment = new Daily_forecast_fragment();
    locationListner = new MyLocationListener();
 // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs, mCurrent_forecast_fragment,
            mHourly_forecast_fragment, mDaily_forecast_fragment);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        if (locationManager == null) {
            getLocation();
            Log.d(TAG, "OnResume locationManager == null");
        }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(isFirstTimeLaunchingTheApp) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart getLocation");
        getLocation();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    if(locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListner);
        Log.d(TAG,"removeUpdates - onPause()");
    }
    //subscribe for background location updates...
    subscription = locationProvider.getUpdatedLocation(request)
            .subscribe(new Action1<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Location location) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Getting Background updates...");
                    MainActivity.this.latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    MainActivity.this.longitude = location.getLongitude();

                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnDestroy Called!");
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And this is the problematic peace of code

```
public void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) {
    //scedule no response from the server task...
    mScheduledFuture = exec.schedule(mNotAbleToGetWeatherDataTask,12, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Log.d(TAG, "getForecast initiated...");
    String API_KEY = "3ed3a1906736c6f6c467606bd1f91e2c";
    String forecast = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + API_KEY + "/" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?units=auto";

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(forecast)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleSwipeRefreshLayoutsOff();
                    }
                });
                //on response from the server cansel the noResponseFromServer task
//on response from the server cansel the noResponseFromServer task
                Log.d(TAG,"OnFailure_ scheduledFuture is CANCELED");
                mScheduledFuture.cancel(true);
                alertUserAboutError();
            }

            //when the call to the Okhttp library finishes, than calls this method:
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleSwipeRefreshLayoutsOff();
                    }
                });
                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        mForecast = parseForecastDetails(jsonData);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.d(TAG, "isSuccessful - run on UNI threth (update display)...");
                              mCurrent_forecast_fragment.updateDisplay();
                                mHourly_forecast_fragment.setUpHourlyFragment();
                                mDaily_forecast_fragment.setUpDailyFragment();
                                toggleSwipeRefreshLayoutsOff();
                                //set the isFirstTime to true so that the next refresh wont get location
                                isFirstTimeLaunchingTheApp = false;

                            }
                        });


                    } else {
                        alertUserAboutError();
                    }
                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
                }
                //on response from the server cansel the noResponseFromServer task
                Log.d(TAG,"OnResponse_ scheduledFuture is CANCELED");
                mScheduledFuture.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    } else {
        toggleSwipeRefreshLayoutsOff();
        alertForNoInternet();
        Log.d(TAG,"Alert No Internet" + 220);
        //is there is no internet cancel the noResponseFromServer task
        Log.d(TAG,"No internet _ scheduledFuture is CANCELED");
        mScheduledFuture.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

This is the code in one of my fragments (it's very similar in all of them )

```
public class Current_forecast_fragment extends Fragment {
private MainActivity mActivity;
TextView mTimeLabel;
TextView mTemperatureLabel;
TextView mHumidityValue;
TextView mPrecipValue;
TextView mSummaryLabel;
TextView mLocationLabel;
TextView mWindSpeedValue;
ImageView mIconImageView;
ImageView mDegreeImageView;
public SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mActivity = ((MainActivity) getActivity());
//        Log.d(mActivity.getClass().getSimpleName(),"OnCreateFragment");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_forefast_fragment, container, false);
    mTimeLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.timeLabel);
    mTemperatureLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.temperatureLabel);
    mHumidityValue = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.humidityValue);
    mPrecipValue = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.precipValue);
    mSummaryLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.summaryLabel);
    mLocationLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.locationLabel);
    mWindSpeedValue = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.windSpeedValue);
    mIconImageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
    mDegreeImageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.degreeImageView);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.current_swipe_refresh_layout);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.orange, R.color.blue, R.color.green);
}
```

my view pager adapter code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private Current_forecast_fragment mCurrent_forecast_fragment;
private Hourly_forecast_fragment mHourly_forecast_fragment;
private Daily_forecast_fragment mDaily_forecast_fragment;
CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb,Current_forecast_fragment current_fragment,
                        Hourly_forecast_fragment hourly_fragment,
                        Daily_forecast_fragment daily_fragment) {
    super(fm);
    this.mCurrent_forecast_fragment = current_fragment;
    this.mHourly_forecast_fragment = hourly_fragment;
    this.mDaily_forecast_fragment = daily_fragment;
    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        return this.mCurrent_forecast_fragment;
    }
    else if (position == 1)            // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
    {
        return this.mHourly_forecast_fragment;
    }else {
        return this.mDaily_forecast_fragment;
    }

}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
}
```

Comment: when/where is `getForecast()` being called?

Comment: In the get location method,which is in on start method (i need the location first to get the forecast) and then when the swiperefreshed layout is toggled.

Comment: I think it would really help to see the logs. if it happens again, save it and post it here

Comment: Thanks, will post the log when happens again :)